# Create images from links

Tags: jquery, image, anchor

```
<td id="anchToImg">
<a href="/mydir/folder/anyImg-1.jpg">my anchor1</a>
<a href="/mydir/folder/anyImg-2.jpg">my anchor2</a>
</td>
```

I need it to be like this after jQuery is applied

```
<td id="anchToImg">
<img src="/mydir/folder/anyImg-1.jpg" class="myiImg"> //changed to image;anchor text removed
<img src="/mydir/folder/anyImg-2.jpg" class="myiImg"> //changed to image;anchor text removed
</td>
```

Note: Directories of a link '/mydir/folder' doesn't change. Image name is given by server sequentially.

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#anchToImg > a').each(function() {
    var $this   = $(this),
        $parent = $(this).parent(),
        $image  = $(document.createElement('img')),
        url     = $(this).attr('href');

    $image.load(function() {
        $this.remove();
        $(this).appendTo($parent);
    }).attr('src', url);
});
```

Inside document ready

Edit: To append the images to other divs

```
$('#anchToImg > a').each(function(e) {
    var $this   = $(this),
        $parent = $(this).parent(),
        $image  = $(document.createElement('img')),
        url     = $(this).attr('href'),
        $thediv = $('#my' + (e+1));

    $image.load(function() {
        $this.remove();
        $(this).appendTo($thediv);
    }).attr('src', url);
});
```

Comment: Well this one worked for me. How can I add class to images with your version?

Comment: @dessol replace `.attr('src', url);` with `.attr({src: url, 'class': 'myiImg'});`

Comment: or $this.attr('class') to grab the class from the link

Comment: Thanks. One more question. How can I append every image not to parent but to existing spans on page with these id's #m1, #m2, #my3 (where #my3 is id of span where third image need to be placed). Thanks!

Comment: @dessol See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164272/create-images-from-links/4165623#4165623

Comment: @tbleckert Oops, sorry. Didn't see your update (although it apparently happened an hour ago).

Comment: Hehe no probs, I should've made a notice about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) and a function, like this, like this:

```
$("#anchToImg a").replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<img />", { src: this.href, "class": "myiImg" });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/aVNGZ/1/). This is safer than the alternative:

```
$("#anchToImg a").replaceWith(function() {
  return '<img src="'+ this.href + '" class="myiImg" />';
});
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TLpEk/).

Comment: What makes you say the first version is "safer" than the second. I would've just used the second method because it looks more logical to me.

Comment: It works but I need it to be applied only to the links with specific directory mask - '/mydir/folder'. I hope I made myself clear :)

Comment: @dessol In that case, use the attribute-starts-with selector: `a[href^=/mydir/folder/]`.

Comment: @Nathan - Injection attacks, quotes, etc.

Comment: Then adjust the selector according to your needs ;)  `$('#anchToImg a[href^="/mydir/folder"]')`

Comment: @dessol -  Just change the selector to `$("#anchToImg a[href*-/mydir/folder")` to filter down to those...sorry it wasn't clear from your example :)

Comment: @Nick Craver Oh, so it's the build-the-html-by-string-concatenation vs. let-jquery-create-the-element. I didn't catch that at first, but makes sense. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#anchToImg a').each(function(i) {
    var img = '<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" class="myiImg" />';
    $(this).after(img).remove();
});
```

Was going to be my shot at this. ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/KzsKF/).) However, @Nick Craver's `.replaceWith()` is probably more suited to the task.

**EDIT**
Also, you could just use `this.href` instead of `$(this).attr('href')` if your selector *only* matches `<a>` elements.

**EDIT 2**
If only links to `/mydir/folder/*` should be replaced, use the [attribute-starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector: `a[href^="/mydir/folder/"]`:

```
$('#anchToImg a[href^="/mydir/folder/"]').each(function(i) {
    var img = '<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" class="myiImg" />';
    $(this).after(img).remove();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/KzsKF/3/).

Answer (score 0):

The requirement seem to have changed:

> How can I append every image not to
>   parent but to existing spans on page
>   with these id's #m1, #m2, #my3 (where #my3 is id of span where third image need to be placed).

Given:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="anchToImg">
            <a href="/mydir/folder/anyImg-1.jpg">my anchor1</a>
            <a href="/mydir/folder/anyImg-2.jpg">my anchor2</a>
            <a href="/no/something.jpg">my anchor1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<span id="m1"></span>
<span id="m2"></span>
```

You can use:

```
$('#anchToImg a[href^="/mydir/folder/"]').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Relative
    var num = href.substring(21, href.indexOf('.')); // Find number
    var $target = $('#m' + num);
    var $img = $('<img />', {src: href, 'class': 'myiImg'});
    $img.appendTo($target);
    //$(this).remove(); -- if the link should be removed
});
```

In order to get:

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td id="anchToImg">
            <a href="/mydir/folder/anyImg-1.jpg">my anchor1</a>
            <a href="/mydir/folder/anyImg-2.jpg">my anchor2</a>
            <a href="/no/something.jpg">my anchor1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<span id="m1"><img src="/mydir/folder/anyImg-1.jpg" class="myiImg"></span>
<span id="m2"><img src="/mydir/folder/anyImg-2.jpg" class="myiImg"></span>
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/KzsKF/8/))

**However**, it is never verified that `#mN` exists before appending the `<img>`!